# How do I import a component from another app with Micro front end Architecture using webpack5 module federation?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to implement Webpack5 module-federation feature in angular. I have followed some tutorials and able to do it. All the tutorials I have followed has shown the process to import a module from remote project using `decl.d.ts` file on a route change.

My current requirement is to show two remotes on a single route.

`Example: I want to show remote1(header) & remote2(side-nav) on the route="/index" in host application`.

To achieve the above requirement , I am assuming that importing the header and sidenav components from remote1 and remote2 to host application will help.

I have done some research to find how to import the components, but I didn't find a solution to import component in host app from remote.

I have exposed the component in webpack.config.js file.

```
  exposes: {
      './HeaderComponent':'./src/app/header/header.component.ts'
    },
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Me also having same requirement, Shell , mfe1, mfe2 running independently , But if i raise an event in shell project want to send some data to mfe1 project and vice versa,

Comment: @Kamal I got the solution for this. There are different ways of doing it. Using the 1.route params , 2. using Window , 3. Using session storage 4. using a library and rxjs observables

Comment: @Nizamuddin Could you please add the approaches you suggested in my project. 
       https://github.com/kamalshaik/module-federation-webpack5-ngular12    go to shell, mfe1,mfe2 run "npm install" and run each project individually "npm start", and try to send data from shell to mfe1 and vice versa.

Comment: @Kamal, I didn't get your question. If you are looking for data passing from  shell to mfe1 and vice versa , you can check my repo `https://github.com/nizam9/Anguar-MFE-using-webpack5-module-federation` . It has all the solutions for data passing between apps.